# Display Map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

Possible many duplicates.

Here is the Logcat dump :

```
09-12 14:21:34.654: I/u(5812): Making Creator dynamically
09-12 14:21:34.694: I/Google Maps Android API(5812): Google Play services client version: 5077000
09-12 14:21:34.704: I/dalvikvm(5812): Could not find method gui.a, referenced from method gqh.a
09-12 14:21:34.704: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934: Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;
09-12 14:21:34.704: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
09-12 14:21:34.704: E/dalvikvm(5812): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-12 14:21:34.704: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-12 14:21:34.704: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-12 14:21:34.714: E/dalvikvm(5812): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-12 14:21:34.714: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-12 14:21:34.714: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-12 14:21:34.714: E/dalvikvm(5812): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
09-12 14:21:34.714: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
09-12 14:21:34.714: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
09-12 14:21:34.714: D/dalvikvm(5812): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
09-12 14:21:34.714: D/dalvikvm(5812): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0c in Lgpr;.a
09-12 14:21:34.714: D/dalvikvm(5812): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
09-12 14:21:34.714: I/Google Maps Android API(5812): Google Play services package version: 5089034
09-12 14:21:34.724: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
09-12 14:21:34.724: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
09-12 14:21:34.724: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
09-12 14:21:34.724: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
09-12 14:21:34.944: I/LoadedApk(5812): connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.maps.auth.ApiTokenService
09-12 14:21:35.024: I/dalvikvm(5812): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
09-12 14:21:35.024: W/dalvikvm(5812): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
09-12 14:21:35.024: E/dalvikvm(5812): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
09-12 14:21:35.024: W/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;
09-12 14:21:35.024: D/dalvikvm(5812): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0019
09-12 14:21:35.134: D/libEGL(5812): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
09-12 14:21:35.144: D/libEGL(5812): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
09-12 14:21:35.154: D/libEGL(5812): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
09-12 14:21:35.154: I/Adreno200-EGL(5812): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4    QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.04.02.02.040.400_msm8960_JB_2.5_CL3744273_release_AU (CL3744273)
09-12 14:21:35.154: I/Adreno200-EGL(5812): Build Date: 06/30/13 Sun
09-12 14:21:35.154: I/Adreno200-EGL(5812): Local Branch: 
09-12 14:21:35.154: I/Adreno200-EGL(5812): Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5
09-12 14:21:35.154: I/Adreno200-EGL(5812): Local Patches: NONE
09-12 14:21:35.154: I/Adreno200-EGL(5812): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.04.02.02.040.400 +  NOTHING
09-12 14:21:35.244: D/OpenGLRenderer(5812): Enabling debug mode 0
09-12 14:22:10.242: W/InputEventReceiver(5812): Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
09-12 14:22:15.788: I/LoadedApk(5812): connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.maps.auth.ApiTokenService
09-12 14:23:01.837: I/LoadedApk(5812): connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.maps.auth.ApiTokenService
09-12 14:23:59.618: I/LoadedApk(5812): connected(), package name=com.google.android.gms ,class name=com.google.android.gms.maps.auth.ApiTokenService
```

Code :

Android Manifest File :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.maps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
<permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
 <!-- Needed -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<!-- Not needed -->
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="*KEY*"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Layout XML :

```
 <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"  
  tools:context=".MainActivity" 
  />
```

Main Activity :

```
package com.example.maps;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends  FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
    }

}
```

Question :
1) It just loads the blanks google page. What else I need to mention?

2) Where can I find the way that will work on all version , as I see many addition in manifest file with change in android version.
Sorry for such a big post.

Few Points : after reading many post in StackOverflow, 
1) It says to add me

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

lines in Manifest. Earlier it was not required as I run the same app without using this.

2) It says to change

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.Fragment"
```

to

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

Otherwise it will crash saying xml inflation issue.

3) There is chance of that the application is signed with different keystore and thus the API key wont work. So I signed the apk with new keystore and used the same sha for generating the API key.

Comment: Its because your key for maps, upgrade it

Comment: get your app key from google api console after creating your own project there.

Comment: follow steps from this link https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start to get your key and then replace it in manifest

Comment: Key, I created today only, Service is on as well, I am writing the key in the manifest file.

Comment: have you included google play services as a library in your project